# update table from other table whithout join

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

Here is the deal. I have a table `T` with many columns but two of interest: `gen_ID`, `ordernumber`.
Records in this table are always by groups of 5 with the `gen_ID` being the same and the `ordernumber` being blank.

So in essence, it looks like this:

```
Gen_ID  ordernumber
233                     
233     
233     
233     
233     
234     
234             
234             
234     
234
```

Now I have a query `Q` that, when executed, randomizes the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

I want to update `ordernumber` with the random numbers of `Q` so it looks like this:

```
Gen_ID  ordernumber
233     3
233     4
233     1
233     2
233     5
234     4
234     5       
234     3        
234     2
234     1
Etc...
```

Any idea on how to do this using MS Access 2010 SQL?

Udate query would be fine but I cannot join the two since I don't have a common ID.
Any suggestions? Note that I can run this magic query once a set of 5 records are created in the table (I don't need to have that done once I have more than one set).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be achieved by SQL alone and will need some VB running alongside.  My approach would be to get your 1 - 5 numbers in a random order stored in an "Array", you can then open up a recordset to "T" and step through one by one assigning a number from your array. You could also loop this process to begin again whenever it detects a new Gen_ID in "T" and thus populate the whole table in one pass.

Comment: I am afraid that you are right. I wanted to avoid using any procedure but it looks like this is what it is going to be like... without the capability to join, there is no way to get there in SQL only. I was just hoping there was a magical statement that I never heard out there... I'll check again later today just in case but thanks for your prompt response Matt.